# How to update v-if with data?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, navbar, vue-reactivity

I'm creating a simple app with vueJS, but I have some trouble with reactivity.

When an user connects to the app he gets a JWT, I store this JWT in my localstorage. And for verifying if a user is logged I just check the token presence.

First of all, is this a good method?

Now I'm trying to update the navbar, when the user is not logged I have 2 buttons "register" "login", when he is logged I want to have my "disconnect" button showing up and the two others disappear.

I have my navbar component with a "v-if" inside for showing or not the buttons.

Currently I have set a Boolean "isLogged" in my data(), How to make vueJS watch this data and update my component when this data updates?

```
    <div class="navbar-item" v-if="!isLogged">
        <div class="buttons">
            <a @click="$router.push('/login')" class="button nav-button is-outlined">
                CONNEXION
            </a>
            <a @click="$router.push('/register')" class="button nav-button is-outlined">
                INSCRIPTION
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a @click="disconnect" class="navbar-item" v-if="isLogged">
        Déconnexion
    </a>
```

```
    data() {
        return {
            isLogged: this.$jwt.hasToken()
        }
    }
```

I'd like to have my navbar updating without have to refresh the component.

Answer (score 2):

Use a computed value instead data.

```
computed: {
    isLogged() {
        return this.$jwt.hasToken()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but where should I call this computed value?

Comment: There's no need to call the computed value, it's automatic. Treat `isLogged` as a variable in your template, just like you are doing now.

Comment: I just tried and my navbar is still not updating except if I refresh the page :/ The computed value does nt update in real time

Comment: Then `this.$jwt.hasToken()` is also not updating. I'd need more context to see how the state of `this.$jwt` is managed. Provide a https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codepen.io/ and I'll help you fix it.

Comment: If this doesn't work then I think there is another way (not a clean way ), create a variable `loggedIn` and update it every time when jwt token is set or get or expired. If your jwt token has expiry set, then you can use setTimeout() to set `loggedIn` to `false` after a particular duration